# DELPHI XE command line to compile localized file

Tags: delphi, localization

Does someone know how to compile a whole localized project (RCN and DFN files) using command line ?
I have used cgrc.exe but does not compile DFN forms only takes care of the RCN file... 
I have a look thru processmonitor and see bds.exe loading the DFM/DFN files ... So may be this is not possible.
If anyone knows...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the DCC command line compiler and write a batch file that does all the compiling.

Here's an example:

```
@echo off
cd eng_core
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
rem Errorlevel test needs to come directly after call.
rem If error occurs code at finalerr will back up one dir.
cd ..
cd eng_coreweb
call build.bat FINAL
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd eng_lspconfig
call build.bat FINAL
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd eng_pvcc
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd eng_tasks
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_block
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_login
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_profman
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_uconsole
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_uninst
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_update
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_updcheck
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_vmigrate
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_visereg
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_vssview
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd instreq
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_vtray
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd gui_wizard
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd svc_pvcc
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd svc_vlaunch
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
cd svc_vservice
call build.bat 
if errorlevel 1 goto finalerr
cd ..
goto off
:finalerr
cd ..
:off
```

and in the seprate subdirectories:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo .
echo ***************************
echo ***Compiling profman.exe***
echo ***************************
if FINAL!==%1! ..\ResetTestFase
if errorlevel 1 goto :err
dcc32 -B -GD profman.dpr
if errorlevel 1 goto :err
copy profman.exe D:\source\output
goto off
:err
if FINAL!==%1! ..\RestoreTestFase
pause
:off
if FINAL!==%1! ..\RestoreTestFase
```

I don't know if/how this explicitly addresses your remarks about the DFN files, but if the IDE processes these, I assume DCC32 does too.

Comment: a BAT file, this is what I thought about, but concerning compiling ressources files and translated DFN into another language, I could not find any doc about this...

Comment: Far better to invoke msbuild from your batch file.

Comment: @Warren Right. This was a pre-msBuild Delphi version ;-)